# casting operator - const vs non-const

Tags: c++, casting, operator-overloading, constants

I have this code sample:

```
class Number 
{ 
  int i;
  public:
    Number(int i1): i(i1) {}
    operator int() const {return i;}
};
```

What are the implications of removing the `const` modifier from the casting operator?
Does it affect auto casting, and why?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If the conversion operator is not const, you can't convert const objects:

```
const Number n(5);
int x = n; // error: cannot call non-const conversion operator
```

Comment: +1 - well earned. Hmmm - I want to cast the value taken from a const object, but I can't, because the conversion (that isn't modifying the source value) isn't const. Stop, look and think and the reasoning is obvious - it's no different to any other method. But I still keep hearing that twilight zone theme. The (at least logical) constness of the source is part of the expected behaviour of the method - what "conversion" means. But then again, consistent rules are, at least, consistent.

Answer (score 6):

The `const` version can be called regardless of whether the `class Number` instance is const or not. If the operator is declared non-const it can only be called on non-const entities - when you try to implicitly use it where it can't be called you'll get a compile error.

Comment: Did you mean "only be called on *non-const* entities"??

Answer (score 6):

If you have a function like this:

```
void f(const Number& n)
{
  int n1 = n;
}
```

It will start giving compilation error if you remove const in the casting operator.