# When to implement a non-const cast operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, constants, typecast-operator

I checked the questions on StackOverflow (especially [casting operator - const vs non-const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325121/casting-operator-const-vs-non-const#2325121)), and [user-defined conversion - cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator), but I found no useful examples for the non-const version.

In which cases would a non-const cast operator make sense?

---

Background (an **edit**): The question arouse from a simple implementation of an *Optional* template class for flat memory layouts. Here I wished an implicit cast to the contained type, and my first approach was like this (without `const`):

```
    template <typename T>
    class Optional
    {
    public:
        operator T() { return value; }
        // ...
    private:
        T value;
        // ...
    };
```

After the compiler reminded me of it, I was curious if this (when returning an **rvalue**) would be simply wrong in any case.

Answer (score 4):

One viable reason is when the cast operator doesn't return a value, but a reference of some sort; you would not want the cast to violate any `const`-ness of the object being cast.

```
class Type {
  HANDLE h;
public:
  operator HANDLE const&() const {
    return h;
  }
  operator HANDLE&() { // possibly want the non-const as well
    return h;
  }
};
```

In my experience through, I think I recall one instance of this and it was to get us out of a pinch.

Comment: What pinch? And even more interesting: did it work well?

Comment: @Wolf, basically the guy wrote the bespoke code and left the company. The code then had to be deployed a few months later, didn't work, was full of memory leaks and so on - this was the shortest way to get it to work and with the compatibility we needed in practically no time. It worked, it was ugly.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious answer is a conversion to an lvalue:

```
class MyInt
{
  int m;

public:
  operator int& () { return m; }
  operator int () const { return m; }
};
```

I can't think of any concrete example beyond that. I imagine it might make sense in some Domain-Specific Languages, where the entire C++ type system is just a vehicle to deliver some syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a case where you have to change the internal state of your object when a casting operator is called:

```
class CounterInt {
private:
  int m_value;
  int m_state;
public:
  CounterInt(int val) : m_value(val), m_state(0) {}
  operator int() {
    ++m_state;
    return m_value;
  }
  int getState() {return m_state;}
};
```

This is not possible if your casting operator is const. Wether or not this is a good idea (or if you should make the state mutable) is another question.

Comment: Ok, this I would probably solve by making `m_state` mutable; this is the purpose for mutable, I think.

Comment: @Wolf in most cases I would agree. It depends on how you intend to use it in the end. This code for instance changes the public interface (`CounterInt::getState()`) of the object, so it is neither logical nor bitwise const. But on the other hand this is completely fabricated and will most likely not appear in any real code.

Comment: Now I discover that your answer is closer to my question than I thought in the first place. Maybe a more productive member function would be more acceptable, for instance something like a random number generator.