# c++ class typecasting operator overloading problem

Tags: c++

These are sources that work:

MyString.h

```
#pragma once

class CMyString {
    public:
        CMyString();
        CMyString(const CMyString &rhs);
        CMyString(const char* param);
        ~CMyString();

    private:
        char* m_pszData;
        int m_nLength;

    public:
        int setString(const char* pszParam);
        const char* getString() const;
        void release();
        CMyString& operator=(const CMyString &rhs);
        operator char*() const;
};
```

MyString.cpp

```
#include "MyString.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

CMyString::CMyString() : m_pszData(NULL), m_nLength(0) {
}

CMyString::CMyString (const CMyString &rhs) : m_pszData(NULL), m_nLength(0) {
    this->setString(rhs.getString());
}

CMyString::CMyString (const char* pszParam) : m_pszData(NULL), m_nLength(0) {
    setString(pszParam);
}

CMyString::~CMyString() {
    release();
}

int CMyString::setString(const char* pszParam) {
    release();
    if(pszParam == NULL)
        return 0;
    m_nLength = strlen(pszParam);
    if(m_nLength == 0)
        return 0;
    m_pszData = new char[m_nLength + 1];
    strncpy(m_pszData, pszParam, m_nLength);

    return m_nLength;
}

const char* CMyString::getString() const {
    return m_pszData;
}

void CMyString::release() {
    if(m_pszData != NULL)
        delete[] m_pszData;

    m_pszData = NULL;
    m_nLength = 0;
}

CMyString &CMyString::operator = (const CMyString &rhs) {
    if(this != &rhs)
        this->setString(rhs.getString());

    return *this;
}

CMyString::operator char*() const { return m_pszData; }
```

StringCtrlSample.cpp

```
#include "MyString.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void testFunc(const CMyString &strParam) {
    cout << strParam << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


    CMyString strData("Hello");
    cout << strData.getString() << endl;

    ::testFunc(strData);
    ::testFunc(CMyString("World"));

    return 0;
}
```

I tried operator overloading about char*() without "const" keyword at MyString.h and MyString.cpp but printed error at compiling. ex) operator char*();

Can someone explain me the difference about adding "const" keyword at the end of char*()?

Comment: Please do not add `**` in your code snippet, these make your code impossible to copy/paste/run directly.

Comment: @Holt oh.. I didn't know that, I'll edit then

Comment: if you want to highlight certain line I'd suggest just adding `// <-----` or something at the end. `**` looks terribly wrong in cpp code

Comment: @michelson thanks I'll keep that in mind :D

Comment: `char* func() const` - `const` at the end means that the object (functions `this`) will not be modified by that function - object before calling and after calling the function will be the same.  Also you may like to take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325121/casting-operator-const-vs-non-const

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751681/meaning-of-const-last-in-a-function-declaration-of-a-class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meaning of 'const' last in a function declaration of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751681/meaning-of-const-last-in-a-function-declaration-of-a-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this function:

```
void testFunc(const CMyString &strParam) {
    cout << strParam << endl;
}
```

`strParam` is a `const`-reference to a `CMystring`, so you can only call `const`-qualified method on it:

```
// Not const-qualified overload
operator char*()

// const-qualified overload
operator char*() const
```

Within a `const`-qualified method, you cannot modify non-`mutable` attributes or call non-`const` methods, which guarantees that your object is not "modified" (at least it should not be from an external point of view).

Note that you should likely convert to `const char*` from the `const`-qualified method, otherwise it would be possible to do this:

```
void testFunc(const CMyString &strParam) {
    // I am modifiying the underlying char array of const variable
    static_cast<char*>(strParam)[0] = '\0';
}
```

So your conversion operator should be:

```
operator const char*() const;
```

Comment: Thank you very much XD
You explained so well that I can understand at once..!

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `const` keyword at the end of a method forbids it to change any member values or call any non-const methods. 
The only exception are mutable values, which can always be modified.

```
class A
{
    int i1;
    mutable int i2;
public:
    void m() const
    {
        // i1 = 5 <- error
        i2 = 5 // <- ok
    }
}
```